# Where to find truck/trailers in Grand Theft Auto Online

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

We'd like to do some truck racing on the Los Santos freeway system. Because you cannot (currently) select a truck in a race "job" we're going to have to do this in freemode.

The problem is we need to get 2-6 truck/trailer units to the same location to start the race.

With this in mind where is the best place to find truck/trailer units in Los Santos/ Blaine County?

Are there places where truck/trailers always spawn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good place to check is the south docks, and on the highways. They also sometimes spawn on the road that runs underneath Fort Zancudo and up at the very north of the map, where the Cluckin' Bell depot is. Unfortunately I don't think there is a place where they always spawn online, but these are some common places.

Comment: Agreed. Paleto Bay is also a good location. We've managed to have a few online truck races.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is still active, but as of 10/16/14, trailers spawn in the same parking lot as the northern most pay n spray. A couple parking lots around that little town also contain trailer spawn locations.